# A diffeomorphism of the torus with constant singular values

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, quasiconformal, singular-values

Let $\mathbb{T}^2=\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1$ be the flat $2$-dimensional torus, and let $0<\sigma_1 < \sigma_2$ satisfy $\sigma_1 \sigma_2=1$.

Does there exist an area-preserving diffeomorphism $f:\mathbb{T}^2 \to \mathbb{T}^2$ whose singular values are constant $\sigma_1 , \sigma_2$?

---

An immediate family of such diffeomorphisms which comes to mind are the affine (geodesic-preserving) maps which are induced by elements of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. However, this family does not cover the entire range of pairs $\{ (\sigma_1,\frac{1}{\sigma_1}) \, | \, \sigma_1 \in (0,1) \}$, since it's countable. Furthermore the set of  $\sigma_1$ which are admissible in this affine family is discrete away from zero, which is its only accumulation point.
 
Are there any non-affine examples?

---

**Edit:**

Robert Bryant has given an answer which shows that there is no non-affine $C^3$ example. I wonder what happens if we allow reduced regularity, say Lipschitz maps whose differential has a.e. the singular values $\sigma_1 , \sigma_2$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no non-affine examples with $f$ smooth (or even $C^3$).  This follows from the fact that such an $f:\mathbb{T}^2\to\mathbb{T}^2$ would lift to a smooth (local) diffeomorphism $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ with constant singular values, and the argument I gave in my answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351546/are-all-maps-mathbbr2-to-mathbbr2-with-fixed-singular-values-affine) implies that such a map $F$ would have to be affine.

Comment: Thanks Robert. BTW, couldn't we get a lift which is an actual diffeomorphism? (not just a local diffeomorphism). Also, are you aware of any obstructions for such a "diffeomorphism with constant singular values" on other manifolds? (e.g. the sphere?). Do you perhaps have a guess regarding the case of a generic metric? (would it admit such a diffeomorphism?)

Comment: @AsafShachar: The lift $F$ already *is* a global diffeomorphism:  $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is clearly surjective, and, because it pulls back the complete metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ to a comlete metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$, it's proper and a covering map, so it's one-to-one.   I didn't need that, though, so I didn't mention it. $$\ $$ On other compact surfaces with nonzero Euler characteristic, there can't be such a map because it would split the tangent bundle into the sum of two line bundles. $$\ $$ There are plenty of metrics on the torus that admit such maps, though.