# Non-trivial $\mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^3}$ maps with constant singular values

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

[It can be proved](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351546/are-all-maps-mathbbr2-to-mathbbr2-with-fixed-singular-values-affine?noredirect=1&lq=1) that all  $\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^2}$ mappings with constant singular values are affine. In three dimensions, however, [there are](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Two-families-of-finite-deformations-with-constant-Yin/6e7e80e2687c1e7689ff7e831f42dfafd11e357c) non-trivial examples, like

$$
\begin{align}
x'&=\lambda_2 x -\frac{1}{\lambda_2}\sqrt{\frac{\lambda_2^2-\lambda_1^2}{\lambda_3^2-\lambda_2^2}}\int_0^{z}\sin f(\xi)\,\mathrm{d}\xi \\
y'&=\lambda_2 y +\frac{1}{\lambda_2}\sqrt{\frac{\lambda_2^2-\lambda_1^2}{\lambda_3^2-\lambda_2^2}}\int_0^{z}\cos f(\xi)\,\mathrm{d}\xi \\
z'&=\frac{\lambda_1\lambda_3}{\lambda_2}z
\end{align}
$$

for an arbitrary differentiable $f$ and $\lambda_3>\lambda_2>\lambda_1$, whose differential has constant singular values $\lambda_3\,,\lambda_2\,,\lambda_1$. So I wonder if one can classify or say something generic about such $\mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^3}$ maps, as is the the case in two dimensions.